# Collaboration between multiple developers in RTC source control

Tags: version-control, clearcase, rtc

In the 'pending changes' view a developer can change the flow target to point at another developers repository. What kind of support is available for collaboration between multiple developers (compared to the ClearCase UCM Stream deliver/rebase model)?

Is it possible to flow to multiple repositories at once ? Perhaps this is not a valid use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "flow target" is a critical part of **merges between Stream**

A repo workspace points by default on one Stream.
But if you want to merge changes published on another Stream, you would:

- add that other Stream to the flow target of your repo workspace
- select it as current
- Accept the change set from that Stream (merges can follow during that process)
- set as current your default Stream (in the "flow target" section")
- deliver the change set to your default stream

That would merge another Stream to your Stream.
(I always recommend accepting changes from other Stream and delivering to your default Stream, rather than delivering your change sets to a non-default Stream)

---

You can point at other repo workspace, but only for **accepting change set** (you cannot deliver change set to other developers).

That is a nice answer to the "developer-is-gone-leaving-reserved-checked-out-file" issue:
If an RTC developer has checked-in his/her work in his/her repo workspace, he/she can leave and another team member can point his flow target to that developer's repo workspace, in order to accept the change set and deliver them to the Stream.

---

> Is it possible to flow to multiple repositories at once ?

No. Only one (Stream/Repo WS) can be declared "current" at any given time.
And regarding adding another repo workspace in your flow target section of your own repo workspace, it is only for *reading* (ie "accept") purpose, not for *writing* (ie delivering) purpose.